# A TextEditingController was used after being disposed when opening another instance of same page is opened

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I have a page called `SearchPage()`. Following are the brief code of that page's controller

```
class SearchPageController extends GetxController {
   final searchTextController = TextEditingController();
   
   @override
   void onInit() {
     super.onInit();
   }

   @override
   void onClose(){
      searchTextController.dispose();
      super.dispose();
   }
}
```

My `SearchPage()` has following code

```
class SearchPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const SearchPage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      final controller = Get.put(SearchPageController());

      return aWidgetHere();
  }
}
```

The `SearchPage` has `TextField` and a `Button` along with other widgets. When this button is tapped, same `SearchPage` is opened but with different contents (But `TextField` remains). When this `Button` is tapped, following code is executed.

```
Get.off(() => const SearchPage(), arguments: [arguments], preventDuplicates: false);
```

Everything works, except that when I tap on `TextField` I get following error

`A TextEditingController was used after being disposed. Once you have called dispose() on a TextEditingController, it can no longer be used.`

Why I am getting this error, because `SearchPage` is re intialized on button tap.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because **SearchPage** and **SearchPageController** gets destroyed when you're calling `Get.off(() => const SearchPage(), arguments: [arguments], preventDuplicates: false);`

My question is, why do you want to navigate to the same page again? You want to update some content based on your button click, so you can use some observable variable to update the content in the same page. It should solve your problem, If you don't understand please the details code.